# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple. Error

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programing and I am trying to assign multiple values to the "contains" variable but I keep getting: "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple."
Can anybody tell me what this means and how to solve it?
Here is the program (tkinter):

```
def myClick():
password = e.get()
contains = "1", "2"

if contains in password:
    myLabel = Label(root, text= "Password Level is Strong")
    myLabel.pack()
```

Comment: You can use ```if any(x in password for x in matches):``` where matches is ```['1','2']```

Comment: @lucal No problem. I thought that you were looking for something like what @ Sujay said so I deleted my comment :D.

Answer (score 0):

Python is giving you this message because you are trying to compare tuple with string but you need to compare string with tuple.. for example with your code:

```
if password in contains:
    myLabel = Label(root, text= "Password Level is Strong")
    myLabel.pack()
```

and i advice you to use 'for loop' if you want to work with tuples or lists..